# Can Azure AD use custom database?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have various applications and each have its own user table. We are looking at the possibility of using Azure AD as a central authentication/authorization provider. Can Azure AD use our existing user tables when it does authentication/authorization? It seems we can import those users into Azure AD, but what if we just want to use the existing user tables, is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible in normal Azure AD.

*It is possible to wire up your own claims provider to Azure AD B2C with custom policies.*

But if you want to use your own store, you should probably just implement IdentityServer or similar yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So in theory, with Azure AD B2C, you can use custom database?

Comment: No. You can only get additional claims from other systems.

Answer (score 0):

As Junnas said, we **can't** use custom database directly.

As a workaround, we can create on-prem Active directory and import your users to it, then install [Azure AD connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect) to sync your users to Azure AD, in this way, the user name and password will store in your local Active directory, and Azure AD work as a authorization provider.

Hope this helps.